# How to call a c# data binding function using jQuery DatePicker?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, data-binding, jquery-ui-datepicker

For the life of me, I am juggling with asp.net calendar and jQuery datepicker.

I have data function ready. And I am trying to remove the existing asp.net calendar because it can't pop up.

So the data binding function must be called based on the date selected by jQuery DatePicker. What's the approach to do it? Is there an event handler in jQuery DatePicker similar to selection_changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#DatePickerId').change(function () {
       //put your desired actions in here
```

});

I think this is what you are asking for, if not let me know.

Comment: The cose you are showing me is still the server side, not client side. Nonetheless why don't you show a sample of both server and client side code mimicing adp.net calendar event using jQuery date picker?